# how to undo the following command ? sudo postconf -e 'content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024'

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

I was trying to setup spam filtering on Ubuntu server with postfix and dovecot already running. I issued the following command

```
sudo postconf -e 'content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024'
```

Now I want to know that how can I undo this command?

Comment: This was cross-posted on SU. Don't do that. Pick whatever site this question is on-topic for and ask it there only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`postconf -d content_filter` will tell you what the default value for the `content_filter` parameter is.
You can then use `postconf -e` to reset the parameter to its default value.

Comment: Thanks man, that solved my problem, I am new to sysadmin thing and still learning. Hope I wont break things.

Comment: The best way not to break things is not to run commands unless you're sure of what they're going to do (**especially** when you're putting `sudo` in front of them...)